What does the phrase "Never has someone been so wrong for being so right" mean?
I came across this comment on a YouTube video:

Never has someone been so wrong for being so right

What does this phrase mean? Is it saying that the person is actually right but everyone thinks they are wrong?

Maybe you should describe the video and tell us what the context is (I mean what it was that the person was talking about)?

It’s likely referencing the English phrase popular on social media, “You’re wrong for this.” It’s a lighthearted way of saying, “You did not just say that!” You might say it in response to a roast (teasing insult) of some kind. The commenter is likely saying that the video creator is figuratively “wrong” for this because they made what the commenter deems a correct observation/comment about a somewhat controversial topic.

Thanks for this answer!

It's an irony. It fits many situations. But let's say you are out on a first date and things are going well, but then you correct a mistake your date has made about the original members of a band, or the precise distance from Stonehenge to Inverness, or the difference between a polecat and a skunk. You insist your date is wrong, bring out your smartphone, and look it up on the internet to prove you are right. Later, when telling someone of that date and its trajectory after you took out your smartphone, you could say "Never has someone been so wrong for being so right."

Got it. Thank you for your answer!

This article Being SO Right Can Be SO Wrong explains:

People tend to get rigid about their beliefs ... and oftentimes the more they perceive they’re being attacked, or disagreed with, the more they dig their heels in and fight back with higher levels of defensiveness (and maybe offensiveness, too).


[W]e love “being right" ... so much we can completely ruin relationships ...


What’s behind this unbending and unrelenting force of rigid rightness?


One word: Ego

In What's So Wrong with Being Absolutely Right,

Judy J. Johnson presents a compelling argument for viewing dogmatism as a serious problem.

Scrolling through the list of books from the above link, we see a key phrase dogmatic belief.
The post

Never has someone been so wrong for being so right

means this person is so dogmatic that he or she may ruin relationships completely.

Understood! Thanks for the detailed explanation!!!
